# How to handle POST requests

Tags: php, wordpress

I am coming from an MVC world and this is quite hard for me to grasp yet. I am trying to figure out what is *the wordpress way* of handling post requests. I looked it up on the web and I found that I should use `add_action` with a function defined in my theme's `functions.php` but I can not figure out how to specify at which uri this function should execute.

For example I have functions a and b that I want to execute on the respective URLs `blog.com/handle_post?function=a` and `blog.com/handle_post?function=b` - the way I see it I need to check from within the functions if `$_GET['function']` is equal to the function that I'm currently in but that makes no sense - first start executing the function then exit if it's not the correct one - that can't be right?

Also about the `handle_post` part of the URL, where am I supposed to define this?

In an MVC application usually the url goes like `site.com/controller/method/data` where it will call the method on the controller you specify in the URL. This is not the case with wordpress, I'm trying to find out how to create a resource at `blog.com/handle_post` for post requests so I wouldn't get 404 not found. Of course I can create a file in the root directory of the blog and point to that but then I wouldn't have wordpress' environment in my script - constants, functions etc.

Comment: What is up with the down voting?

Comment: umm, lack of research effort

Comment: @RahilWazir you must be kidding me, I've spend more than 2 hours on this already........

Comment: Wordpress documentation is quite terrible for me - no examples what so ever.

Comment: Please give more details about what exactly you're trying to achieve, specially about the POST data origin.

Comment: @vard I added some additional explanations, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the general [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook to catch your request and process it. Let's say you submit your form to the page where it stands, with an hidden input helping identifying the function to be called:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_my_form" />
  <!-- your form inputs here... -->
</form>
```

And then in *functions.php* :

```
function process_my_form() {
    // Check if there is any post data and if it comes from our form
    if(empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST['action']) || $_POST['action'] != 'process_my_form') {
        return;
    }

    // Check if inputs submitted are valid
    if(!isset($_POST['my_field']) || empty($_POST['my_field'])) {
        $_SESSION['my_form_error'] = __('Invalid input');
        return;
    }

    // If all data are valid, process your form, then redirect to whatever with :
    wp_redirect(home_url() . '/my-page-to-redirect/');
}
add_action('init', 'process_my_form');
```

Then in your template you can check on `$_SESSION['my_form_error']` to display the error message if input is invalid.

Please not that if you need to include wordpress functionality in a stand alone script one day, you can include the WP core with *wp-config.php*:

```
require_once(getcwd() . '/wp-config.php');
```

Comment: Wow, is it just me or is this awful code design? Thank you for your answer, especially the last part, I think it is going to be of great value to me!